# How to see which queries has been executed. (mysql)

Tags: sql, mysql

I run a site at localhost and I would like to see which queries are executed.
I've seen that some pages execute a lot of queries (eg 107) and I would like to see which are all these,as I think they're a lot..
(I know how many queries are executed, as the queries are executed through a function which also stores at a global value the number of queries)

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the function that you use to execute queries, so that it will log them into a file or just output them at the bottom of the page for instance.
There is no tool or (built-in) function that would tell you what was executed on some specific request.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace a mysql database [as described at this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/making-trace-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the [MySQL general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html). Quite useful during development, it will show you literally everything that your server is doing.

As such, I wouldn't recommend enabling it on a production server (at least not for long).